# Apache: 403 Permission denied after syslogd restart

Tags: apache, centos, permission-denied, syslog

After syslogd retarted, Apache started logging Permission denied errors. Nothing has changed on the box. Permissions are 755 across the board and config file hasn't changed. I even set permissions to 777 on all folders leading to the web folder and restarted httpd.  SElinux disabled. CentOS release 5.7. Any ideas?

```
[user@host log]$ sudo cat messages
Jun 23 04:02:55 systools syslogd 1.4.1: restart.

[user@host log]$ head /etc/httpd/logs/error_log
[Sun Jun 23 04:03:02 2013] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Sun Jun 23 04:03:02 2013] [notice] Digest: done
[Sun Jun 23 04:03:04 2013] [notice] mod_python: Creating 4 session mutexes based on 256 max processes and 0 max threads.
[Sun Jun 23 04:03:05 2013] [notice] Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jun 23 04:04:16 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.190] (13)Permission denied: access to /incident/rss.php denied
[Sun Jun 23 04:09:14 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.190] (13)Permission denied: access to /incident/rss.php denied
[Sun Jun 23 04:14:14 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.190] (13)Permission denied: access to /incident/rss.php denied
[Sun Jun 23 04:19:15 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.190] (13)Permission denied: access to /incident/rss.php denied
[Sun Jun 23 04:24:16 2013] [error] [client 192.168.1.190] (13)Permission denied: access to /incident/rss.php denied

    Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at systools.corp.webex.com Port 80
```

Comment: Nothing change? Who is the owner of the web root directory and files? use ls -al to see

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 4096 Jun 26 09:52 /var/www/html

Comment: The timestamp is current due to troubleshooting the issue. Even with /var/www/html chownd to apache:apache, and httpd restarted, i still get permission denied.

Comment: did you do it recursively? CD to /var/www then do `chown -R apache:apache html/` Also make sure apache is the user/group you have been using.

Answer (score 0):

Changed permissions of files and restarted httpd.

```
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 775 {} \; find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \; /etc/init.d/http restart
```